Install multiple PostgreSQL silent
Hopefully a simple question.
If I Install PostgreSQL x64 Version 15 like this
            Process process = new()
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = exePath,
                    Arguments = $"--datadir \"{dataInstallPath}\" --servicename PostgreSQL.{version}.Service --serverport {port} --prefix \"{versionPath}\" --mode unattended",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                }
            };

It installs it on the path, I provided (Example D:\PostgreSQL)
If I want to install a second instance of it with the same Command but another path (C:\PostgreSQL), it tries to install it on the old path (D:\PostgreSQL) because it gets the old path from the Registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL
Is there any way to prevent this so i can install multiple PostgreSQL instances?
The background is as follows.
We need the database on a customer server and it may be that a customer database already exists in which we do not want to work.

I would use containers instead. Why would you install at the OS level nowadays?

This is the company's specification, I have absolutely no influence on it.
